# How to avoid overrated item after set state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I have an function to get the data from firebase, 
and I want to set data into a state after getting,
so I just declare an array and push all data to them after that I setState this array with my state

**But when I log these state or render it, I got some issues With RN 0.61.2, It's Work perfect In RN 0.58.0 I don't Know Why/How!!!**

when I log the state I just see overrated data "I just have 4 items in DB" but the logger print to me more than tens,
and when I just render these data "state" they tell me

> JSON value "5" of type NSNumber cannot be converted to Nsstring

So how can I avoid that?

here is my code Snippet

```
  this.state = {
      RecommendedProviders: [],
}

componentDidMount() {
      this._recommendedProvider();
}

_recommendedProvider = () => {
    let Recommended = [];
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref('recommendationProviders')
      .once('value')
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
          Recommended.push({
            gKey: childSnapshot.key,
            id: childSnapshot.val().id,
            username: childSnapshot.val().username,
            service: childSnapshot.val().service,
            aboutMe: childSnapshot.val().aboutMe,
            coordinates: {
              longitude: childSnapshot.val().coordinates.longitude,
              latitude: childSnapshot.val().coordinates.latitude,
            },
            city: childSnapshot.val().city,
            mobileNumber: childSnapshot.val().mobileNumber,
            token: childSnapshot.val().token._55,
          });
        });
        console.log('Recommended', Recommended); //when i log this i can just see array of 4 item
        this.setState({RecommendedProviders: Recommended});
      });
    //   .then(() => this.setState({RecommendedProviders: Recommended}));
  };
```

UI

```
<FlatList
     horizontal
     data={this.state.RecommendedProviders}
     renderItem={({item}) => {
        console.log('@item/', item); /when i log this i can just see more than 4 item maybe 20 :D
     }}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first about that logger:

> JSON value "5" of type NSNumber cannot be converted to Nsstring

This error is because `keyExtractor` expects a string as returned value. So, to avoid it, you can try this:

```
<FlatList
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => 'item' + index}
/>
```

Finally, about your log:

I created an expo's snack with your gist, wich SDK is based on react-native 0.59, you can check it [here](https://snack.expo.io/BJUWOq_YS). I also tried to simulate your async fetch with the code below and it worked fine.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 2000, [
    { id: 1, username: 'test', service: 'example' },
    { id: 2, username: 'test', service: 'example' },
    { id: 3, username: 'test', service: 'example' },
    { id: 4, username: 'test', service: 'example' },
  ]);
}).then(res => {
  const providers = [];

  res.forEach(item => providers.push(item));

  this.setState({ RecommendedProviders: providers }, () =>
    console.log('object', this.state.RecommendedProviders)
  );
});
```

I believe that may be the solution to downgrade your RN version, if it does not negatively impact your application.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hey @LuizMariz, Thanks for answer but sadly didn't work for Both *keyExtractor and renderItem* , here is the log after follow your answer , Log Item https://i.imgur.com/wv6yd2X.png ,, here is the Recommended array i declared https://i.imgur.com/8VVYJV9.png

Comment: @OliverD can you create a Github [gist](https://gist.github.com/) of your component and package.json. And also a print of the errors.

Comment: Here's https://gist.github.com/anastely/729052eed00f391c34b33b0d5f7aaaaa

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad you want to help, but sadly didn't work in this version I just do two things but your static data and put the data come from firebase but still issues, and it's an old project and just upgrade it and handle all third party library to Proportional with RN v 0.60+ :( and take too time  , so what's advice you can tell to me :(

Comment: Well, in this case i will keep thinking. As an advice: give you a break, sometimes the solution just pops out in random moments

Comment: OH MY GOD, the issue related with F* style, I just pass to shadowOffset a number, and they accept an object as i see here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.60/shadow-props#shadowoffset and when I pass something like this  `{width:5, height:10}` the error JSON value "5" of type NSNumber cannot be converted to Nsstring

Gone!